# Randomly Selecting Values From Array Without Repeating

Tags: arrays, for-loop, random

Hi: I am new to Javascript and HTML, been studying on my own for a month. I am doing a small project where when I click a button, 3 random workout exercises appear in a table. I will attach my code to show what I have so far.

---

**Issue:** When the for loop runs, it prints the same randomly selected item 3 times, not 3 different items.

---

**Goal:** When I click a button, the array prints 3 different array values.

```
var workouts = ['situps', 'planks', 'hollow rock']
var copy = workouts.slice();

var table = '';
var i = 1;

for(var j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    var answer = copy.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*workouts.length), 1); 
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<td>';
    for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
        table += answer;
    }
    table += '</td>';
    table += '</tr>';
}

function potato() {
document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML += ('<table border = 1>' + table + '</table>');
}

//Output: Sit ups, Sit ups, Sit ups
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow.

The problem with your code showing the same output is happening because of your for loop. You are going into loop just one time because the `i` variable is `1`.

What you really want to do is have as many loops as the number of elements you want to show.

One way to show 3 unique and random elements from an array would be like this:

```
var workouts = ['situps', 'planks', 'hollow rock'];
var copy = workouts.slice();

var table = '';

for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
  var answer = copy[random];

  table += '<tr>';
  table += '<td>';
  table += answer;
  table += '</td>';
  table += '</tr>';

  //Removing the selected element so it won't show again.
  copy.splice(random, 1);
}

function potato() {
   document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML += ('<table border = 1>' + table + '</table>');
}
```

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you so much, I was struggling for awhile on this one...

Comment: Sure thing! Just to make sure because Im new, its just the check mark next to the answer right?